# Should I use different variables or update the same variable multiple times?

Tags: laravel

I wrote a query like this,

```
$customQuery = Modal::something();
$customQuery = $customQuery->where('some', 'thing');
$customQuery = $customQuery->get();
```

but someone pointed out that I am doing it wrong. They said I should use a different variable in each line, like:

```
$customQuery = Modal::something();
$filteredQuery = $customQuery->where('some', 'thing');
$results = $filteredQuery->get();
```

Both queries gave the same result. Is there anything wrong in what I did?

P.S. that is a simple example my query is a lot longer and have some if else in between as well.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it in this case, though you don't need to reassign the variable at all. You're not (and really can't) reusing `$custom->query` somewhere else in another instance.  Both `$customQuery` and `$filteredQuery` refer to the same QueryBuilder object. But as I said, you don't need to do that at all. Once you've assigned `$customQuery`, you can use all of the functions to it and not need to worry about the return value until you actually grab the results with `->get()`

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your query at all. Sometimes giving different names makes it difficult to debug so I think it's best to use the same variable as you did.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with it at all. It is just a preference of readability